# Get Different Value From An Associative Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two associative arrays as given below:

```
$array1 = array("field1"=>1,"field2"=>1,"field3"=>1,"field4"=>1,"field5"=>1);

$array2 = array("field1"=>1,"field2"=>0,"field3"=>1,"field4"=>0,"field5"=>1);
```

Now I want to merge and find the value which is different.

for that ***I tried [array_intersect](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_intersect.asp):***

```
$result =  array_intersect($array1,$array2) ;
```

But it returns the following output:

```
Array
(
    [field1] => 1
    [field2] => 1
    [field3] => 1
    [field4] => 1
    [field5] => 1
)
```

I need the output to be

```
Array
(
    [field2] => 1
    [field4] => 1
)
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [array_diff_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-assoc.php).

it Computes the difference of arrays with additional index check.

```
$array1 = array("field1"=>1,"field2"=>1,"field3"=>1,"field4"=>1,"field5"=>1);

$array2 = array("field1"=>1,"field2"=>0,"field3"=>1,"field4"=>0,"field5"=>1);

$result =  array_diff_assoc($array1,$array2) ;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

LIVE DEMO : https://eval.in/924926

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple. You have to look for **array_diff_assoc()** function.

```
 How it Works :- Returns an array containing all the values from array1 that are 
            not present in any of the other arrays (in your case $array2).
$array1 = array("field1"=>1,"field2"=>1,"field3"=>1,"field4"=>1,"field5"=>1);
$array2 = array("field1"=>1,"field2"=>0,"field3"=>1,"field4"=>0,"field5"=>1);
$output =  array_diff_assoc($array1,$array2) ;
var_dump($output);
```

Hope it helps!